# TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId]»

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, azure-migrate

I try to migrate Azure DevOps boards from one organization to another.
And I use this tool: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools

I follow the instructions in the document but errors occur:

```
[16:43:59 INF] Processor: WorkItemMigration 
[16:43:59 INF] Migration Context Start: WorkItemMigration [16:43:59 INF] WorkItemMigrationContext::InternalExecute ... 
[16:44:00 INF] MigrationClient: Access granted to https://dev.azure.com/yyy/ for xxx (xxx@xxx.com) ... 
[16:44:03 INF] MigrationClient: Access granted to https://dev.azure.com/zzz/ for xxx (xxx@xxx.com) 
[16:44:04 INF] Migrating all Nodes before the Processor run. 
[16:44:05 WRN] The node \xxx\Iteration\Sprint 1 is being excluded due to your basePath setting. 
[16:44:06 INF] Querying items to be migrated: SELECT [System.Id], [System.Tags] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan') ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc ... 
[16:44:13 INF] Replay all revisions of 20 work items? 
[16:44:13 INF] Found target project as test-han [16:44:13 INF] [FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget] is enabled. Searching for work items that have already been migrated to the target... 
[16:44:13 ERR] Error running query Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId]». 
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision) 
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Query(String wiql, IDictionary context) 
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemsFromQuery(TfsWorkItemMigrationClient wiClient) 
in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 40 

[16:44:13 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId]». 
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision) 
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Query(String wiql, IDictionary context) 
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemsFromQuery(TfsWorkItemMigrationClient wiClient) 
in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 70 at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItems() 
in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 30 
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.FilterExistingWorkItems(List 1 sourceWorkItems, TfsWiqlDefinition wiqlDefinition, TfsWorkItemMigrationClient sourceWorkItemMigrationClient) 
in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 54 
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() 
in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 120 
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() 
in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47 [16:44:13 ERR] WorkItemMigration The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
[16:44:13 INF] Application is shutting down...
```

Below is my config file

```
{
"ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
"Source": {
"$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
"Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/yyy/",
"Project": "y01",
"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
"AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
"AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
"PersonalAccessToken": "MY_TOKEN",
"LanguageMaps": {
"AreaPath": "Area",
"IterationPath": "Iteration"
}
},
"Target": {
"$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
"Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/zzz/",
"Project": "z01",
"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
"AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
"AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
"PersonalAccessToken": "MY_TOKEN2",
"LanguageMaps": {
"AreaPath": "Area",
"IterationPath": "Iteration"
}
},
"GitRepoMapping": null,
"LogLevel": "Information",
"Processors": [
{
"$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
"Enabled": true,
"ReplayRevisions": false,
"PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
"UpdateCreatedDate": true,
"UpdateCreatedBy": true,
"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
"WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
"LinkMigration": false,
"AttachmentMigration": false,
"AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\temp\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\",
"FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
"SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
"WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
"FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
"PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
"AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
"AttachRevisionHistory": false,
"LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
"GenerateMigrationComment": false,
"NodeStructureEnricherEnabled": null,
"NodeBasePaths": [
"/"
],
"WorkItemIDs": null,
"MaxRevisions": 0
}
],
"Version": "11.11",
"workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
"WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
"sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
},
"Endpoints": {
"InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
{
"Name": "Source",
"EndpointEnrichers": null
},
{
"Name": "Target",
"EndpointEnrichers": null
}
]
}
}
```

I follow some solutions from other articles, setup a custom column called 'ReflectedItemId' for workitem type 'Product Backlog' (just this
type).
And apply this self-define process (inherited form Scrum) to both source & destination project. And still can not fix it.

Then, I try to run the query shown above(error log) with Wiql playground extension on source project.
It says that "@TeamProject " is not a valid name, which means the query from source project is not working, not to mention the succeeding tasks
. Am I understand it right?

Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

##### Solution:

This field is used to releate WorkItems migrated.
You need to create a custom process by inheriting the existing process.
Set this custom process as process type of the destination project.

Further, In each WorkItem type of Interited process, you need to add field `ReflectedWorkItemId`.

##### Steps:

1. To create an inherited process, follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops)

[image]

2. To add field `ReflectedWorkItemId` for each work item, follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops),
   You have to create a field (for the first WIs) or use an existing field (for the next WIs) with name `ReflectedWorkItemId`

[image]

3. Retry migration

Note: If you have been follow this steps, you should put in your config file this value `Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId` for `ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName`.

Comment: I have improved this answer. You need to approve this.